# Hibernate mapping resource from external project

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping-resources

I am wondering if it is possible to map resources from an external project?

What I mean:

I have project A with hibernate.cfg.xml which will be communicating with JMS and added to buildpath project B, which has classes and HBM mappings for them.

I would like to create queries from project A, which will ask the database and return proper objects of classes defined in project B.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

A simple `<mapping resource="/project/location_of_hbpm" />` in the config file doesn't work...

Comment: if the configuration file is in classpath then you will be able to access it. It is not required to be in same project.

Comment: The project is in the classpath, I have even tried including it as jar file... The problem is that hibernate-config is in this firsrt project and it throws an error that unknown entity...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to map resources from external locations/projects as long as they are in `CLASSPATH`.

In your case, you can't because if you do, it would be a 'Circular Dependency' and it won't work.

```
Project B --> Depends on --> Project A (which has config/xml files).
```

So you can't make

```
Project A --> Depend on --> Project B.
```

If you want to use the Project B 'POJO/Classes' in Project A, then try to extract those classes from 'Project B' into a separate JAR file and let both Project B and Project A depend on it.